# How to Write HTML String in C# to Formatted Text in MS-Excel

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I want to write the following html string in ms-excel using c# code

```
<b>bold text</b><i>italic text</i><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">googlelink</a><font color="#000099">red</font>
```

but in excel, the expected output should be with formatting like

> **bold text** *italic text* [googlelink](http://www.google.com)

Can anyone please suggest how this can be implemented?

Comment: Excel doesn't support hyperlinks which don't occupy the whole cell.

Answer (score 0):

Saving excel document as xml-spreadsheet allows you to play with text styles(bold/italic/etc.)

Sample content from excel xml-spreadsheet:

```
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0"> 
    <Cell><!-- you data is here -->
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        This is <B>Bold, <I>Bold Italic, </I></B><I>and Italic</I> text</ss:Data>
        </Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
```

But I don't know how to put hyperlink yet.

[See samples here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Clipboard.SetText` to put the HTML string on the clipboard then paste to Excel, but as stated in the comments above hyperlinks need to occupy a full cell.

To test try copying this:

```
<table><td><b>bold text </b><i>italic text </i><font color="#FF0000">red</font></td><td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">googlelink</a></td></table>
```

then select a cell in Excel and choose *Paste > Paste special > Text*.